# How do I put a sentence after the welcome sentence and before the user input data?

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using Dialogflow to develop an Action on Google Assistant. Currently, the Welcome Intent to displays a default welcome sentence, and I want to add additional sentence after the welcome sentence to describe more clearly how the action help user, What can I do?

I tried to add a response text in welcome intent, but it not work.

[The additional sentence I want to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHCtf.png)

Comment: I think you have to add some more info about what you want, because some users won't understand your task ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding multiple responses will not put all of them in the reply - Dialogflow will pick one of them randomly to use.

What it sounds like you are looking to do is add a second "Simple Response". In general - you probably should avoid a second "Simple Response". It doesn't always work well on all platforms, and if you're sending it each time, it becomes unnecessary.

You can do this through a fulfillment webhook or by adding additional response types to the Dialogflow UI. I tend to prefer the webhook, since you can do it with code, and you can choose exactly when you want to send it.

However, if you want to send it every time using the UI:

In the Response section, enter the first response that you want to send - you probably already have it there:

[image]

Then, click on the "Google Assistant" tab that is there and make sure the switch for "Use responses from the DEFAULT tab as the first responses." is turned ON.

You can then enter the second message you want to send underneath.

[image]